# Error "Cannot resolve Symbol editText" in Android Studio MyFirstApp tutorial

Tags: android, mobile-application

I'm new to Android Studio and Android development. So I was following the tutorial given by developer.android.com and I'm having an error in this line : `EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);`
The error is saying that : cannot find symbol variable editText .

This is part of my code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: `editText` is not part of `activity_main`

Comment: please copy the complete compiler error-message to the question

Comment: add your xml file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that you have assigned the `id` for your `EditText` in the `activity_main.xml` as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Just hit this same error! For me, it occurred when the I made a mistake trying to type in a new name over the default name of the widget. The Android tutorial has been impressive so far, but I wish they had put in an explanation of the line in code in question rather than skipping over it. That would have made it a bit easier to figure out what was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the edit text in your XML. If not, perhaps the id you gave it differs from editText.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your XML code it leaves it a bit difficult, however I would guess if you go back to your XML code where you have the edit text xml code. Add this `android:id="@+id/editText".`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you OP. I went back to the activity_main.xml and noticed the ID was different somehow in the top right corner under attributes for the Text box. Changed the ID back and reran the app and no issues/

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you need to write `editTextTextPersonName2` instead of `editText` to match the definition in `activity_main.xml`:

```
android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
```

The code shall thus be as follows:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`R.id.editTextTextPersonName2` cause problem. You can try `R.id.editText` and follow the recommendation mentioned by others by adding `android:id="@+id/editText"` in `activity_main.xml`