# Error Trying to create App following guide on android studio 4.1 with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

following the guide: "Build your first app" using Kotlin:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#BuildIntent

Android Studio 4.1

until "Build a simple user interface" all works fine.

then after finishing "start another activity" appears the error "Unresolved reference: editText"

- that error appears first time at "Build an intent"

error message:
e: C:\Users\Rodrigo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\myfirstapp\MainActivity.kt: (17, 52): Unresolved reference: editText

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

code:
src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFirstApp"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

src\main\java\com\example\myfirstapp\DisplayMessageActivity.kt

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.widget.TextView

class DisplayMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)
    }

    val message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE)

    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
        text = message
    }
}
```

src\main\java\com\example\myfirstapp\MainActivity.kt **error is here**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun sendMessage(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val message = editText.text.toString()
        val intent = Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

src\main\res\layout\activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/edit_message"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

src\main\res\values\strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377621/error-cannot-resolve-symbol-edittext-in-android-studio-myfirstapp-tutorial

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem with the MyFirstApp following the Android Development guide at "https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui".

The problem does in fact lie in id of the Plain Text field in the example on that page as depicted in Layout view in Figure 5.

The id listed in that figure is "editTextTextPersonName".
Once you change the id to "editText" and re-run the program it works fine in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `EditText` at activity_main.xml.
You have written

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

But in your layout you don't have 'EditText' with that id. So that is causing problems

Comment: I've followed the instructions in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: They have added `EditText`, but you have `TextView`instead.

Comment: changing EditText to TextView dont fix either

Comment: You have to change TextView to EditText. And also you have to change its id

Comment: redo using Java instead Kotlin, then works fine. just 1 issue, but with fix already in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481408/android-first-application-string-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error